# Branch link on Android only opens app if it already in task list

Tags: android, branch.io

I have a branch link that I tap on from the standard mail client in Android.

If my target app is running (so is in task list) then the link successfully redirects to open the app as expected.

If my target app is not running (I have closed it) then when tapping on the branch link it seems to briefly go to another page (white with red header) before this is closed and I am returned to the mail client and my app has not been opened.

The branch link is configured to use a URI scheme and is not an App Link.

Comment: Alex from Branch here: this is very strange. Could you post the link you're trying so that we can debug further?

Comment: Yes - the link I am using is https://vtes.app.link/CScrVAuR7B

Comment: Hmm...not seeing anything immediately wrong there. Is this a problem only from the standard mail client, or from *all* apps? Could you also post the relevant sections of your manifest and activity?

Comment: Woops - turns out it was self induced! There was some logic that checked path and failed in certain circumstances, which was causing the app not to start. thanks anyway.